# Want to create user defined function in R programming for splitting data into train and test and return sample, train and test from the function

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

```
totalrows=nrow(x)
s=sample(seq(1,totalrows),0.7*totalrows)
train=x[s,]
test=x[-s,]
```

How should I put this data in user-defined function so I don't have to repeat it and when I pass a file I read, it will split the data and return the sample(s), train and test data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions to create the test and the train set.

```
#Creating train set
create_train_split <- function(dataset){
library(caTools)
set.seed(123) 
split = sample.split(dataset, SplitRatio = 2/3)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
return(training_set)
}

#The same way creating test set
create_test_split <- function(dataset){
library(caTools)
set.seed(123) 
split = sample.split(dataset, SplitRatio = 2/3)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
return(test_set)
}
```

You can call this function in the following way

```
train_set = create_train_split(dataset)
test_set = create_test_split(dataset)
```

You can edit the splitRatio and set it to the Ratio you want your dataset to be.

Comment: @Mitesh Shah if this has answered your question please give an upvote.